# I am not able to print Niara symbol along with Amount .NET Framework > POS for .NET

Tags: c#

I need to write the *naira symbol* uisng C#. My code is:

```
PrintTextLine(printer, TruncateAt("₦" + (TotalPrice).ToString("#0.00"), 12).PadLeft(15, ' '));
```

But the above code prints `?` instead of `₦`. I opened Notepad and copy-pasted the naira symbol from the internet and printed it without any issues, my printer printed  it correctly without any configuration.

How can I write this symbol using code?

Comment: You probably have a problem with the encoding of the string data that is being sent to the printer. But it is very difficult to give advice on how to fix problems like this. You need to be aware that .Net internally works with Unicode data (UTF-16), and the printer probably expects character data in a different encoding or "code page".

Comment: What does `PrintTextLine` do?

Comment: It print the text on receipt